# Displaying files on browser

Tags: javascript, html

/*I have a website. [www.ivancapistran.com](http://www.ivancapistran.com). If you click on the document icon it loads a div to display my source code. The problem is when I display my .c files it doesn't capture the top includes. For example its missing #include <stdio.h> in one of the loads. It skips anything between < >. How can I use javascript to display what's missing. For example if your on the website and you click on cFiles, advancedProgramming, Homeworks, hw01, calendar.c its missing <stdio.h> */

```
function openFile(fileName){
        // instead of load, change the src of the embed
        //alert(fileName);
        
        if (viewerPageShow == 0){
            changePosition('viewerPage');
            document.getElementById('viewerPage').style.display = 'block';              
            viewerPageShow = 1;
            changeZIndex('viewerPage');
            
            if (bottomNavViewerPageShow == 0){
                
                bottomNavViewerPageShow = 1;
                appendBottomNav('viewerPage');
            } else{ 
                    
                    
            }                                                           
            
        } else if (viewerPageShow == 1){
                
            changeZIndex('viewerPage');
            document.getElementById('bottomNavViewerPage').style.backgroundColor = '#565656';                   
            if (bottomNavWorkPageShow == 1) {
                document.getElementById('bottomNavWorkPage').style.backgroundColor = '#778899';
            }
            if (bottomNavCalculatorShow == 1) {
                document.getElementById('bottomNavCalculator').style.backgroundColor = '#778899';
            }
            if (bottomNavMatrixPageShow == 1) {
                document.getElementById('bottomNavMatrixPage').style.backgroundColor = '#778899';
            }
            if (bottomNavAboutPageShow == 1) {
                document.getElementById('bottomNavAboutPage').style.backgroundColor = '#778899';
            }
        }
                
        
        setTimeout(viewerPageZIndex,50);
        $('#documentViewerFileNameSpan').html(getDocumentFileNames(fileName));
        
        //var convertToText = " ";
        var fileToEmbed = "<div id='viewerPageContent' class='col-md-12' style='position:absolute;top:65px;height:500px;background-color:Cornsilk;border:1px solid gray;overflow-y:auto;'>   </div>";
        $('#viewerPageContent').remove();
        $('#viewerPageContentContainer').append(fileToEmbed);   
        
        jQuery.get(getDocumentFiles(fileName), function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            //convertToText = data;
            //alert(convertToText);
            
            $('#viewerPageContent').html("<pre style='background-color:black;color:SpringGreen;'>" + data + "</pre>");
            
        });
        
        //alert(convertToText);
        //alert(convertToText);
        //var fileToEmbed = "<embed id='viewerPageContent' src='"+getDocumentFiles(fileName)+"'  class='col-md-12' style='position:absolute;top:65px;height:500px;background-color:Cornsilk;border:1px solid gray;'>";
        //var fileToEmbed = "<div id='viewerPageContent' class='col-md-12' style='position:absolute;top:65px;height:500px;background-color:Cornsilk;border:1px solid gray;scroll-y:auto;'> Test: "+ convertToText +" </div>";
        //alert(convertToText);
        
        //$('#viewerPageContent').remove();
        //$('#viewerPageContentContainer').append(fileToEmbed);                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render the contents of a text file directly as HTML, so its not that is not displaying it, it is just converting it in HTML. For example, <> are tags in HTML, so <stdio.h> is not missing but it converted into HTML tag, look below -

[image]

You can avoid this by 2 ways -

**1. By sanitizing the data**

You have to sanitize your data before rendering it in HTML.

First sanitize as below -

```
var sanitizedData = $('<div>').text(data).html();
```

Then render the HTML with this sanitized data -

```
$('#viewerPageContent').html("<pre style='background-color:black;color:SpringGreen;'>" + sanitizedData + "</pre>");
```

Your final function would look like -

```
jQuery.get(getDocumentFiles(fileName), function(data) {         
    var sanitizedData = $('<div>').text(data).html();
    $('#viewerPageContent').html("<pre style='background-color:black;color:SpringGreen;'>" + sanitizedData + "</pre>");         
});
```

**2. By not rendering data as HTML -**

First just create the pre tag inside viewerPageContent -

```
$('#viewerPageContent').html("<pre style='background-color:black;color:SpringGreen;'></pre>");
```

Then render data as text inside pre -

```
$("#viewerPageContent").find("pre").text(data);
```